# Attorney client privilege in the Trump and Clinton investigations

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, hillary-clinton, fbi

In the wake of the FBI raid on his attorney, President 
Trump has said that [attorney-client privilege is dead.](https://www.npr.org/2018/04/10/601153729/does-fbi-raid-on-trump-lawyer-cohen-mean-attorney-client-privilege-is-dead) Undoubtedly that is an exaggeration, but it brings up a fair question:

Has attorney-client privilege been handled in a consistent and impartial manner in the Trump and Hillary Clinton investigations?

Comment: Re "But Trump's exaggerations often seem to have a kernel of truth...", perhaps you would care to cite an example or two?  Because I really can't think of any.

Comment: Simply put attorney-client privilege doesn't count when the investigation is into crimes committed jointly by the attorney and client.

Comment: @jamesqf -- that's a different discussion. I'll remove it from the question.

Comment: The top answer is fairly comprehensive, but I believe you may get equally as good an answer, possibly with cited precedent, from law.se

Answer (score 14):

The [*Ryan Lucas* NPR article cited](https://www.npr.org/2018/04/10/601153729/does-fbi-raid-on-trump-lawyer-cohen-mean-attorney-client-privilege-is-dead) already answered this:

> But that doesn't mean that attorney-client privilege is a magical
>   blanket that covers any and all scrutiny. It doesn't. There are, in
>   fact, a number of exceptions.
>
> Perhaps the most frequently cited is known as the "crime-fraud
>   exception." Boiled down to the basics, this says that discussions
>   between a lawyer and client about a future crime or fraud are not
>   privileged. Conversations about past crimes, however, are.
>
> So a mafia boss can't send an email to his attorney that says, "I want
>   you to arrange the murder of my enemy" and then keep that email out of
>   evidence in court by citing attorney-client privilege.
>
> Sandick points to a few other notable
>   exceptions. If a lawyer is communicating with a third party, for
>   example, those conversations are not privileged. Or if a lawyer is
>   giving business advice, that is not protected either.

Therefore if Trump or some person close to Trump engaged Cohen as a "*fixer*", tasked with persuading or coercing certain parties into concealing reports of some embarrassing debauch or unlawful deed, (via threats of litigation or by providing hush money then drafting possibly unactionable [NDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement)s, or maybe via other even more unorthodox methods), such *fix*itious communications would not be protected.

The same article outlines the painstaking formal methods by which seizures of privileged materials are separated from unprivileged materials *without* injustice:

> Now, back to the question of attorney-client privilege: If
>   investigators seize privileged materials, such as electronic
>   communications, in a raid, that kicks into gear a special process that
>   creates a "clean team" to review those items.
>
> "This is an independent team, typically comprised of lawyers and
>   investigators, that will review the seized documents for any
>   privileged information," says Michael Moore, a former U.S. attorney
>   for the Middle District of Georgia.
>
> "They will then isolate that information from the regular
>   investigative team. In essence, they wall themselves and the
>   information they find that might be privileged off from the
>   investigation."
>
> The goal is for the clean team to protect a defendant's right to enjoy
>   the privileged communications with an attorney — while the team can
>   see materials protected under the privilege as it goes through the
>   evidence, the lawyers prosecuting the case cannot.

(Engineers and programmers may recognize the technique as being quite similar to [clean room design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design), used to reverse-engineer *BIOS* functions and *OS* hooks while avoiding copyright infringement.)

Comment: Few points. 1 - investigators cannot even *look* at privileged communications, and you have to *read* it to see if it is a privileged message. Who does the reading? 2 - what is the crime in paying off porn actress? Because that needs to be the presumption in looking for messages to or from her (which is the stated reason for seizure). 3 - aside from any potential crime in there how it is a part of investigation of collusion between Trump and Russia, which is the reason for mueller's existence as special counsel?

Comment: @AcePL None of these points are relevant to the question or the answer. You seem to be more concerned with making a political point than with getting the question author the answer they are looking for.

Comment: @Philipp those points raise issues that cause the answer to not really answer the question. Which is about double standards in treating the c-a-p of persons in question, not the C-A-P itself.

Comment: @AcePL, Re "*Who does the reading?*": please see revised answer.

Comment: @AcePL: Re "crime in paying off porn actress".  1) If it was done to affect the election, then the money (which the lawyer says came from his own funds) would be an illegal campaign contribution.  2) Ms Daniels has also stated that she was physically intimidated to get her to sign the agreement, creating a reason to think that the lawyer might have either arranged for it, or knew of it beforehand,

Comment: Good info, but doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @WilliamJockusch, Perhaps the question could be made clearer by editing it to include the words: "*Has attorney-client privilege has been handled in a consistent and impartial manner in both the Trump and Hillary Clinton investigations?*"

Comment: @agc - again, while you;re correct in how those teams work, under the Constitution they are illegal - you cannot see privileged client-attorney communication while you're an agent of the government. That's my issue. Also, the way they were obtained was also unconstitutional.

Comment: @jamesdf  "If it was done to affect the election, then the money (which the lawyer says came from his own funds) would be an illegal campaign contribution." No, it would be an independent expenditure.

Comment: @AcePL Try actually finding out how to back up your claims, rather than just constantly spitting out your preexisting misinformed opinion. 
 Everything was done in accordance with DoJ policies and rather thoroughly detailed case law from the supreme court regarding the seizure of evidence from an attorney. Cohen's defense team will of necessity try to pursue various angles to have evidence from the search invalidated, but this will most likely be on procedural and technical grounds ("this phrase here is too vague") rather than constitutional ones (this is already settled precedent).

Comment: @AcePL - apparently, and we won't know until charges are filed, if any, a lot of the potential crime involves campaign finance laws (if campaign funds were used, or, given the amount, if this would reasonably be considered an "in kind" contribution to the benefit of the campaign), and a number of financial and wire-transfer disclosure and anti-fraud regulations. Given that they were paying her off and didn't want anyone to know about it, there's a good chance they fudged the facts on disclosures that carry hefty penalties for false statements.

Comment: +1 for explaining the limits of attorney/client privilege (which I knew) AND then explaining how an investigation must be conducted once a search warrant has been served to protect the legally privileged information (which I didn't know).

Answer (score 4):

I like your question.  I don't know why someone voted it down, though it might be better for legal than political.  The opening question "is it dead" is too broad but you make it nice and specific here:

> it seems fair to ask whether or not attorney-client privilege has been
>   handled in a consistent and impartial manner in the Trump and Hillary
>   Clinton investigations

I hate to answer a question like this as I'm a legal-noob, but this [USA-today article seems to address your question pretty well](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2018/04/09/michael-cohen-fbi-raid-attorney-client-privilege/501564002/).

As noted in some of the answers above, attorney-client privilege doesn't apply if the client and the attorney conspire to break a law.

"How would they know" - fair question.

"How do they avoid obtaining privileged and protected information?" - also a fair question.

The article points out that warrants (as opposed to subpoenas) are issued if there is fear that documents will be destroyed.  It's rarely done that a warrant is issued for a law office, but if a federal judge OK's it, it's legal.

> it's very unusual for the Department of Justice to permit prosecutors
>   to raid an attorney’s office and that’s because you want to be careful
>   not to get privileged material," said Litman, who teaches at the UCLA
>   School of Law and continues to practice at the law firm Constantine
>   Cannon.
>
> "In order to get the OK to raid Cohen's office, prosecutors would have
>   had to get approval from high up — in this case from Deputy Attorney
>   General Rod Rosenstein — and demonstrate to a federal magistrate both
>   probable cause and the need for a warrant instead of a subpoena (such
>   as a concern that Cohen might destroy evidence), Litman explained."
>
> In addition, the probable cause would have to relate to a crime
>   centered on Cohen, not Trump or someone else. "You can’t use it as end
>   run around to get to the client," Litman said.

So, in short, if they think a lawyer has broken the law, and they have sufficient evidence to get a warrant and they believe that lawyer might destroy his records, then it's perfectly legal to investigate that lawyer.

"But, OK, so the lawyer broke the law, what about all the stuff the client told the lawyer that was privileged?"

All of that's still privileged.  What's not privileged is when the client and the lawyer conspire to break the law together.

from the article:

> There will also be a "taint team" to examine everything before it is
>   handed over to prosecutors to make sure that those conducting the case
>   never see any material that might be "tainted" by attorney-client
>   privilege.
>
> The only way the prosecution would be permitted to examine any
>   material that might otherwise fall under the attorney-client umbrella
>   is if it is determined to be part of a crime jointly undertaken by the
>   attorney and the client. But for the privilege to be nullified under
>   the "crime-fraud exception," Litman said the taint team would have to
>   get the approval of the court before the material could be presented
>   to the prosecution.

I used to work in investment banking and we had something called a wall, between those who had inside information (investment bankers) and those who didn't (traders/debt/equity floors and research).   There's something like that here, where the people who read what they find in Cohen's office, pick out what they think falls outside of attorney client privilege, give that to a judge, who, if it meets approval, then and only then, Team-Mueller gets to read it.

As far as I can see, it's all legal, all straight up and in no way a violation of attorney-client privilege.  Now, if documents are slipped under the wall - so to speak, that would be a violation.   If deputy attorney general Rod Rosenstein did this as a favor to Mueller, not because the warrent was warrented, that would arguably be a witch hunt, but if the wall was respected, not a violation of attorney-client privilege.

And if stuff is leaked that should be kept private, that's unethical and a smear campaign.    But my understanding, as long as the warrant was offered based on good evidence and in good faith and as long as the wall is maintained, then attorney-client privilege was in no way violated.

I find your point on Hillary interesting, because, despite all the talk, James Comey concluded his investigation fairly quickly.   Guilty by association is different than violation of attorney client privilege.   I think, in both Trump and Hillary's cases, there's a lot of "He's guilty/she's guilty" before the verdict is in.  I don't know enough about the various Hillary situations to know if attorney-client privilege ever came up.   In Trump's case, as he said it in direct response to the Warrant and "Raid" on Cohen's office just a couple days ago, it's much easier to pin-down.

All this is basically what AGC said.  I'm not sure I added anything other than quoting a different article.  I think he gave a good answer.

Comment: Good answer, however, from POV of constitutionalists like Alan Dershovitz, the concept of "taint team" is unconstitutional because they are agents of government and that alone prevents them from even looking at privileged communications, let alone pick what is and what's not relevant. As for the HRC - her attorney was found to be committing a crime of obstruction of justice but was immunized by FBI.

Comment: And after that she was acting as HRC's attorney, and her c-a communications (which, we now know was containing conspiracy to commit acrime) was not only not invaded, the evidence of that was returned to her (attorney) exaclty on the grounds of it being c-a-p comms.

Comment: @AcePL, Are you talking about this limited immunity deal? "In exchange for giving the laptops they used to the FBI, Mills and Samuelson were given a limited immunity agreement from the Department of Justice, the Democratic source said, that they would not face prosecution for any information that was found on those laptops." https://www.cnn.com/2016/09/23/politics/cheryl-mills-immunity-hillary-clinton-emails/index.html "the evidence of that was returned to her (attorney) exaclty on the grounds of it being c-a-p comms." How do we know about that evidence if it was returned to her?

Comment: In any case, "taint teams" seem to predate the Hillary investigation and the Russian investigation by quite a bit, so Trump's supposed "kernel of truth" that this is somehow a new phenomena is patently false. And if materials are returned to Cohen for being client and attorney privilege, I'm sure it will be done so after the taint team has had time to sift through it (just like it was done for Hillary Clinton's lawyer). Fox News seems to be jumping the gun on this one.

Comment: @AcePL and Stephen, Thank you for the bits on Hillary.   Interesting stuff.

Comment: @userLTK, Just to be clear, I was quoting AcePL in my second quote in my first comment, not CNN. The CNN link pertains only to my first quote. I am still unsure of where AcePL got the idea that the evidence of a crime was returned to Mills if nobody knew what it was (except for the taint team). That sounds like speculation to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Doesn't really answer the question, either. That's OK -- seems it's not an easy one.

Comment: @AcePL - "POV of constiutionalists LIKE DERSHOVITZ" - "like him" being the key term, since his view, even among constiutional scholars is very much a minority one, as is his claim that it's impossible for POTUS to obstruct justice. The "they're all the same" seems like a lazy contention for a scholar. Hell, it is for a middle-schooler. I'd need something more concrete, like showing that it's a process fraught with leaks and no protections against the leaks, and if it was, such evidence would quickly be disallowed by a judge, based on exactly that.